# Interface an IMU?

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone interfaced a 9DOF IMU like Sparkfun's Razor or the APM's from DIY Drones?

Each has software already, but what level of information should the IMU publish to ROS?

Thanks,

Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45444/interface-an-imu?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard ROS interface for that is [sensor_msgs/Imu](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7